# Words not breaking to next line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place text next to an image and have the white container wrapped around the text and image stay the same size and the text to move to the next line when it is about to go over the edge. Right now the text will just continually make the white div bigger and the text will stay on the same line.

I have tried using the following:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

I tried each of these individually putting them in each of the nested divs and none of them would actually prevent the div container from getting larger, the text would stay on the same line. Cannot tell if other properties are interfering with these,

here is my code:

```
            <div class="main-textbox">
                <div class="main-textbox-welcome">Clergy</div>

                <div class="main-textbox-parish-clergy">
                    <img src="images/priest/orthodox-priest.jpg" class="main-textbox-parish-clergy-img">
                    <p class="main-textbox-parish-clergy-text">Lorem </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
.main-textbox{
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 90rem;
    width: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;

         &-parish {

               &-clergy {
                   display: flex;
                   align-self: flex-start;

                &-img {
                    display: flex;
                    height: 40rem;
                    margin-left: 10%;
                }

                &-text {
                    display: flex;
                    align-self: center;
                    margin-left: 10%;
                    font-size: 2rem;
                }
               }
           }
    }
```

Comment: Yes my code is SASS

Comment: I can't see the `word-wrap` or `word-break` items in your exampled Sass. Word breaking will only occur when the text exceeds the horizontal size of the container. If the container is a flexible size, this won't happen, as it will instead stretch the container element. As you're using flexbox then I suspect this is expanding to accommodate your word(s).